# Alert dismissing using Twitter Bootstrap is not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alert, dismiss

I'm using Google Chrome. 
 
Using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap), I want to add a simple alert, unfortunately the [alert](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts) is not dismissing when the x is pressed!

Here's my code based on [alert](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts) documentation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div class="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
    </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

And I also tried:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>    
    <div class="alert">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
    </div>      
    </body>
  </html>
```

What is missing to make it dismiss ?

Comment: Not strange, since you have completely forgotten bootstrap.js :)

Comment: It works :) .... Thanks :) .... You can put it as answer so that I can increase your points :)

Comment: Never mind, just a typical blunder - happends all the time :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to [davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407478/davidkonrad)'s comment. 
The solution is trivial, by adding:

```
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Another cause could be: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery.  Then should add `%script{ :src => '//code.jquery.com/jquery.js' }`

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [small, customisable, jquery plugin](https://github.com/davesag/jquery-bs3Alert) that injects a properly formed Bootstrap 3 alert (with or without close button as you need it) with a minimum of fuss and allows you to easily regenerate it after the box is closed.

See https://github.com/davesag/jquery-bs3Alert for usage, tests, and examples.